# Apex error - variable doesn't exist when attempting to access record value

Tags: salesforce, apex

Trying to access the value of a record passed into my method.  Debug shows the values from the record but when I try to reference them I get 'variable does not exist' errors.

Here is a snippet:

```
public static void method1(list<billing__c> passBillings){
            list<billing__c> bills =  passBillings;

            for (list<billing__c> newbills : bills){
                if (newbills.balance__c > 1){
                    system.debug('has balance');
                }
            }

            }
```

I want to be able to use the balance to continue on the if statement but get this error:
Variable does not exist: balance__c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is confusing a `List<Billing__c>` and a `Billing__c`. The sObject has a property `Balance__c`; the List does not.

```
public static void method1(list<billing__c> passBillings){
        list<billing__c> bills =  passBillings;
```

You don't need `bills`. It's just a new name for the same object instance.

```
        for (list<billing__c> newbills : bills){
```

`bills` is a `List<Billing__c>`, so if you're iterating over it your iteration variable `newbills` needs to be of type `Billing__c`. That makes its name rather confusing;  I would suggest just doing

```
        for (Billing__c bill : bills){
            if (bill.balance__c > 1){
```

Once you make those changes, your Apex will compile.